# compiled application not loading in real device

Tags: react-native

For the life of me, I can't figure it out. All it shows is spinning without end and i am confused on the order of the life cycle happening. Basically, it goes to login or home screen and it works correctly on emulator but not on real device. I am on react 16.8.6 and react-native 0.60.5 environment.

I am getting started with RN and my debugging tools are not great. But for now just used Alert to see and the logic that was supposed to redirect to login/home screen is never reached. The Alerts shown are in the following order:

```
BS
mount2
render
mount1
```

My code is below: if the token exists, load home screen. else load auth screen is what I wanted to achieve but for now the line:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(!goToLogin ? 'App' : 'Auth');
```

is never reached and so, spins a lot. Any help?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StatusBar, View, Alert} from 'react-native';

import {
  getUserToken,
  loggedInToAssociation,
  extractToken,
} from '../shared/loggedinUser';
import {setLanguage} from '../shared/localization';
import {appOptions} from '../config';
import Spinner from '../components/Spinner';

export default class AuthLoadingScreen extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      languageLoaded: false
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    Alert.alert("mount1","oumnt1") // shown
    loggedInToAssociation()
      .then(details => {
        // details is an array now

        setLanguage(details['language']);
        this.setState({languageLoaded: true});
        Alert.alert("mount2","oumnt2") // SHOWN
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setLanguage(appOptions.defaultLanguage);
        this.setState({languageLoaded: true});
        Alert.alert("mount3","oumnt3")

      });
  }
  // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
  _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    const userToken = await getUserToken();
    Alert.alert("bs","bs") // SHOWN
    const tokenInfo = extractToken(userToken, 'both');
    let goToLogin = true; // force user to go to the login page
    if (tokenInfo.length == 2) {
      goToLogin = false;

    }
    Alert.alert("bs2","bs2") // NEVER SHOWN
    this.props.navigation.navigate(!goToLogin ? 'App' : 'Auth');
  };

  // Render any loading content that you like here
  render() {
    if (this.state.languageLoaded){
      this._bootstrapAsync().then(s=>{
        console.log(s)
      }).catch(e=>{
        console.log(e)
      })
    }
    return (
      <View>
        <Spinner />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you check your debug console when running on device? There might be an unhandled promise rejection. The promise didn't go through but nowhere to handle the catch (consider try-catch scenario for this context).

It might be having a problem with this method.

```
extractToken(userToken, 'both')
```